# Unable to configure sub-domain to different Google App Engine Application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, subdomain

I currently have a domain registered in domains.google (Googles own registrar) and a google app engine configured to that domain.  So that www.{domain}.com and {domain}.com both end up at the GAE's first application.

However i'm attempting to point another subdomain (such as api.{domain}.com) at a different application, however since google have removed their 'synthetic records' i'm not able to do what they suggest in their help documentation.

Notes:
* I have setup and got working a second application/project that has an appspot.com address
* I only currently have the free tier of the GAE for now (i'm attempting to evaluate if its possible to do what i need without putting down money up-front or having to use the free-trial... yet)

Any ideas/solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you point to the procedure you're following and clarify which step doesn't work and how?

Comment: Hi, i've tried this one... https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6009957?hl=en and quite a few google searches / google help documents related to the cloud developer console but none seem to indicate how to do it.

Comment: That's just DNS configuration. You want this one - the GAE custom domain config: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application

Comment: Thanks for your help @DanCornilescu.  Your url allowed me to focus in a bit more on the solution.  The documentation about wildcards matching App versions etc didn't seem to work.  The final solution was to setup '*' as the 'name' for the A and AAAA type records.  Then for each application goto 'App Engine/ Settings/custom domain' tab and setup the sub.domain.com address (+ add TXT verification to the records) to be able to map fully.